# How do I make a randomly generated string an instance of a class in python?

Tags: python, class, oop, instance, instance-variables

I'm writing code that can generate an 16 digit account number and 4 digit password.
The account can store a balance which I'm keeping track of via a class (hopefully using the 16 digit number as the instance of said class)

My code bellow shows where I'm at

```
card_pin_dict = {}

class Account():
    

    def __init__(self,number,pin):
        self.number = number
        self.pin = pin

    def balance(self):
        balance = 0
        return balance



def gen_account_num():

    global new_card_num
    global randpin

    new_card_num = "40000" + str(random.randint(1000000000, 9999999999)) #creates account number

    randpin = str(random.randint(1000, 9999))

    card_pin_dict[new_card_num] = randpin
    print(card_pin_dict) #This is to check the password against account number later 

    print(f"Your card number:\n{new_card_num}\nYour card PIN:\n{randpin}")
```

which works fine.
What I want to do...

```
def gen_account_num(): 

    #bottom of function
    new_card_num = Account(new_card_num,randpin) #using the number as the instance 


def print_balance()

    id = input("What is your account number?) #4000001029458302 (example)
    
    print(id.balance)
```

Comment: remove the globals in (the frist) `gen_account_num()`. Add these as parameters to (the second) `gen_account_num()` (`gen_account_num(new_card_num, randpin)`) and make it return the object instance `new_card_num`. Once the user inputs the id, call `gen_account_num(new_card_num, randpin)` (you need to set a default value for randpin).

Answer (score 0):

Make your first `gen_account_num` a class method.

```
card_pin_dict = {}

class Account:

    def __init__(self, number, pin):
        self.number = number
        self.pin = pin
        self._balance = 0

    @property
    def balance(self):
        return balance

    @classmethod
    def gen_account(cls):
        
        new_card_num = "40000" + str(random.randint(1000000000, 9999999999)) #creates account number
    
        randpin = str(random.randint(1000, 9999))
    
        card_pin_dict[new_card_num] = randpin

        return cls(new_card_num, randpin)

a = Account.gen_account()
```

`__init__` is usually a "dumb" method, the dumber the better. Class methods are a good way to encapsulate code needed to generate the arguments to the dumb initializer.

We make `balance` a property, rather than a public attribute of the class, to limit the ways you can modify the balance. Above, we make it a read-only property by not defining a setter. Only methods you provide (like `deposit` or `withdraw`) should modify the value of the `_balance` attribute.

For `print_balance`, you first need something that maps account numbers to instances of `Account`. This could be a simple `dict`, similar to the one you use to map card numbers to pins. Then `print_balance` looks something like

```
def print_balance():
    id = input("...")
    acct = account_dict[id]
    print(acct.balance)
```